# JPA - Not able to access non entity @mappedsuperclass in manytoone relationship

Tags: jpa

Any idea how to access mappedsuper class in manytoone relation ship in jpa. here is my code snippet.

Message is the non entity mapped superclass(no table for message)
SystemMessage is an entity class table name is SYSTEM_MESSAGE//union subclass
OrganizationMessage is an entity class table name is ORGANIZATION_MESSAGE//union subclass

When I try to access organization notification domain object from ORGANIZATION_NOTIFICATION
organization notification table has message_id column(Message)manytoone relationship.

It is not loading and it thrown message is not entity. even i tried @entity instead of @mappedsuperclass but it is not loading message. i should access both system message and organization message through organization notification

```
@MappedSuperClass
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS )
public class Message extends BaseDomain implements Comparable<Message>
{
  private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger( Message.class );

  @Id
  @Column( name = "MESSAGE_ID" )
  @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MESSAGE_PK_SQ" )
  @SequenceGenerator( name = "MESSAGE_PK_SQ", sequenceName = "MESSAGE_PK_SQ",       allocationSize = 1 )

  private Long id;
  @Column(name="MESSAGE_NAME")
  private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table( name = "SYSTEM_MESSAGE" )
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE )
public class SystemMessage extends Message
{
//some persitant variables
}


@Entity
@Table( name = "ORGANIZATION_MESSAGE" )
@Inheritance( strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE )
public class OrganizationMessage extends Message
{
//some persitant variables
}


@SuppressWarnings( "serial" )
@Entity
@Table( name = "ORGANIZATION_NOTIFICATION" )
public class OrganizationNotification extends BaseDomain implements Comparable<OrganizationNotification>
{
@Id
  @Column( name = "ORGANIZATION_NOTIFICATION_ID" )
  @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "org_notification_pk_sq" )
  @SequenceGenerator( name = "org_notification_pk_sq", sequenceName = "org_notification_pk_sq", allocationSize = 1 )
  private Long id;


 //Here is the issue. when i try to access message it says it is not entity otherwise it is not loading if i use entity in message and not saving. 
 @ManyToOne( targetEntity = Message.class )
  @JoinColumn( name = "MESSAGE_ID", insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = false,referencedColumnName="MESSAGE_ID" )
  private Message message;

}
```

Could you please give me any suggestion on this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that another entities have an association with Message instances proves that Message must not be a MappedSuperclass, but an Entity.

Annotate Message with `@Entity` rather than `@MappedSuperclass`.

MappedSuperclass is used to inherit fields and/or associations in entities that have nothing else in common.

Comment: Thank you! I did one more change. I changed Message concrete class as abstract Message class. It is working fine now.